# How to stop calling useEffect again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

> Container

```
import { InputField } from './InputField';

const sleep = (time: number) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, time, ''));

export const Container = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    (async () => await sleep(1000))();
    async function fetchMyAPI(time, value) {
      await sleep(time);
      setInputValue(value);
    }
    fetchMyAPI(1000, 'vbc1');
    fetchMyAPI(2000, 'dgi1');
  }, []);

  const inputChange = (value) => {
    setInputValue(value);
  };

  return <InputField inputValue={inputValue} inputChange={inputChange} />;
};
```

> InputField

```
export const InputField = ({
  inputValue,
  inputChange,
}: {
  inputValue: string;
  inputChange: (value: string) => void;
}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setValue(inputValue.slice(0, -1));
  }, [inputValue]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
    inputChange(event.target.value + '1');
  };

  return <input value={value} onChange={handleChange} />;
};
```

inputValue above can change multiple times.
also a local variable in input is used to display , and inputValue is slightly different from it. So when we keep track of InputValue , we pass the cleared data to the local variable. And vice versa, we modify the data to put in the inputValue.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setValue(inputValue.slice(0, -1));
  }, [inputValue]);
```

> Every time we call handleChange : we do setValue and inputChange. Thus, we change the value variable and the inputValue variable. After the inputValue is changed, useEffect is called which observes the inputValue. And overwrites exactly the same value of the Value variable. This is problem!

What is the correct solution to this problem?

Comment: `Every time we change InputValue, we change the local variable, but it already contains the correct value in case we call inputChange. And that's the problem!` Did not understand this? Can you rephrase

Comment: Every time we call handleChange : we do setValue and inputChange. Thus, we change the value variable and the inputValue variable. After the inputValue is changed, useEffect is called which observes the inputValue. And overwrites exactly the same value of the Value variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a boolean state `effectRan` to track whether the effect already ran or not, and only invoke the effect's logic if `effectRan == false`, then set it to `true`.

When the effect runs again with it as `true`, have it set it back to `false` to prepare to run again in the next change.

I changed the code a bit to highlight the approach:

```js
const {useState, useEffect } = React
const InputField = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
  const [effectRan, setEffectRan] = useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!effectRan) {
      setValue(prev => prev + '-');
      setEffectRan(true)
      console.log('Effect just ran');
    } else {
      setEffectRan(false)
    }
  }, [value]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return <input onChange={handleChange} value={value} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<InputField />, root)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```